# Wordpress CSS formating issue

Tags: css, wordpress

A don't understand why the sidebar of my Wordpress blog does not have consistent formatting for H3 tags.

There are two PHP-generated un-styled H3 tags in the sidebar, followed by my own manual H3 tag.  The first two appear larger than the third, yet they are identical tags.

The site in question [is here](http://www.superlogical.net).

The contents of sidebar.php are:

```
<div class="sidebar">

<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Sidebar') ) :
    $widget_args = array(
        'after_widget' => '</div></div>',
        'before_title' => '<h3>',
        'after_title' => '</h3><div class="widget-body clear">'
    );
?>

<?php the_widget( 'GetConnected', 'title=Get Connected', $widget_args); ?>

<?php the_widget( 'Recentposts_thumbnail', 'title=Recent posts', $widget_args); ?>

<?php endif; ?>

</div>

<div class="sidebar">
<h3>Choice links</h3>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.annimac.com.au">Annimac Consultants</a> - Futurist & Life Coach</li>
    <li><a href="http://www.melvilletenniscentre.com.au">Melville Tennis Centre</a> - Great social tennis</li>
</ul> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a wrong selector in your CSS stylesheet. It is `.widget h3`, but should be `.sidebar h3` (look into your HTML code). Besides - `<p>&nbsp;</p>` is a big "no, no". One does not set the layout using empty and not semantically neutral block elements. Just use margins or paddings instead.